# "Session-based" or "session based"

Tags: hyphens

I have such sentence "Create a session based authentication", and I think that correct way to spell it, is like this: "Create a session-based authentication".

Am I right? I have followed answer for this question as a rule: [correct use of hyphens to connect two words](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22293/correct-use-of-hyphens-to-connect-two-words?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right.  This hyphen is often left out in error.  I work as an editor for a sports blog, and this is a correction I have to make very often.

In addition to the thread that you linked, [this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/hyphen) is a good overview of when to use the hyphen.  For more threads like it, you can google "compound adjective hyphen."